# A time tracker with screenshots and usable Jira integration

Tags: jira, integration

There are tons of time trackers available that claim to be 'time trackers with screenshots and Jira integration', however, after a closer look all of them (at least the ones that I found) suffer critical flaws.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could recommend a reliable time tracker with the following features:

- Windows Desktop client
- Screenshots, preferably customizable
- Application usage breakdown
- Keyboard and mouse activity
- Sync work time with Jira tasks **in real-time**, i.e. new Jira task appears in tracker immediately and the captured time is written to Jira task in real-time (or quite frequently)
- Proper integration with Jira so that all trackers/employees can work within the same Jira projects.
- Jira task filtering and search. This is to avoid scrolling hundreds of tasks in the Desktop Client
- Sync time to any Jira project task, not necessarily the tasks where the current user is the assignee.
- Auto-pause when an idle time detected
- The monthly price is no higher than $10/mo

Hubstuff, Timecamp, TimeDoctor are the closest candidates, unfortunately they lack some of the features above.

Comment: Software recommendations are out of scope on super user. There is a [software recommendation exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) you could try.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [DueFocus](https://duefocus.com/) . This app may help you according to your requirements and requests. Besides, right now you have an opportunity to download and check it for free. Time tracker is available as a beta.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, like a overview of the software you're suggesting. Follow some of the topics based on [this topic](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/880618) and [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1434756/edit) your answer accordingly.